# EC2 error when running ec2-bundle-vol to create AMI for instance storage

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am facing with problem when try create ami with ec2-bundle-vol for my instance running that cloned from http://thecloudmarket.com/image/ami-f485a6a6--racemi-centos-6-i386-hvm-20141112085400

from console ssh connect to my instance

```
>export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=~/.ec2/pk-aws.pem
>export EC2_CERT=~/.ec2/cert-aws.pem
>export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_72
>export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_72/jre
>export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.7.0_72/bin:/opt/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin
>export EC2_AMITOOL_HOME=/usr/local/ec2/apitools
>export EC2_HOME=/usr/local/ec2/apitools
>export PATH=$EC2_AMITOOL_HOME/bin:$PATH
>source ~/.bashrc

>ec2-bundle-vol -k $EC2_PRIVATE_KEY -c $EC2_CERT -u 440170694567 -r i386

output: 

Setting partition type to bundle "/" with...
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/ec2/platform/linux/image.rb:253:in `set_partition_type': Non-standard volume device "/dev/xvda2" (FatalErr
or)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/ec2/platform/linux/image.rb:71:in `initialize'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/ec2/amitools/bundlevol.rb:172:in `new'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/ec2/amitools/bundlevol.rb:172:in `bundle_vol'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/ec2/amitools/bundlevol.rb:231:in `main'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/ec2/amitools/tool_base.rb:201:in `run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/ec2/amitools/bundlevol.rb:239
```

info more about volumne with df and lsblk

```
>lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0    2G  0 disk
|-xvda1 202:1    0  102M  0 part /boot
`-xvda2 202:2    0  1.9G  0 part /

>df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda2      1.9G  1.9G     0 100% /
none            503M     0  503M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1       99M   27M   68M  29% /boot
```

Any ideas what can be wrong?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  The problem was that the file system I was using to put the bundled image on was ext3 , rather than ext4.  Run:

df -T

and make sure the type is ext4:

/dev/xvdo      **ext4**   51475068 7379772  41473856  16% /amiimage

I had to create a volume of type ext4 for the command to work.

Comment: Thanks @swolfe, with df -T it show me ext3 for devices, so how do i can change to ext4?